# Replacing consecutive symbol with another

Tags: c, char, symbols

I am having programming lessons but there is something I couldn't figure out in a little part of my task. So far I have written all the things required from me and my code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    unsigned int length;
    unsigned int length2;
    char s1[15], s2[15];

    puts("Hi! Enter a word to calculate its length!:  ");
    gets(s1);

    length = strlen(s1);
    printf("\n-> %s has %d characters!", s1, length);

    puts("\n\nEnter another word to calculate its length!:  ");
    gets(s2);

    length2 = strlen(s2);
    printf("\n-> %s has %d characters!", s2, length2);

    if(strcmp(s1,s2)==0)
    {
        puts("\n\n-> Words are equal!");
    }
    if(strcmp(s1,s2)<0)
    {
        puts("\n\n-> The second word is greater than the first one!");
    }
    if(strcmp(s1,s2)>0)
    {
        puts("\n\n-> The first word is greater than the second one!");
    }

    puts("\n\n...\n\n");

    char _add[15];
    puts("Type a word to add the first word!");
    gets(_add);
    strcat(s1, _add);

    printf("\n%s added to the first word. Now the first word is:\n",_add);
    puts(s1);
    length = strlen(s1);
    printf("\nNow the first word(%s) has %d characters!", s1, length);

        char repl = '!';
//chrstr????
    return 0;
}
```

I am supposted to replace the 3rd consecutive symbol with the '!' symbol and display new s2. But I'm stuck with replacing part (in chrsts???), how can I replace it with "the 3rd consecutive symbol"

edit// another problem is that I should confirm that s2 has 6 or more characters.. how do I do that?

Comment: **Warning:** Don't use `gets()`. Use `fgets()` instead. `gets()` is vulnerable to buffer overrun and is no longer a part of C.

Comment: If  `length>=6` your `while` loop never terminate.

Comment: Can you give an example? for "aaaaabbccc" should it be "aa!!!bbcc!" or "aa!aabbcc!"?

Comment: @Ashiquzzaman I changed the description.

Comment: @AlexLop. I have no idea. Nothing was given in the task. It just says "In the s2 string, provided that its length is greater than 6 characters, replace the 3rd
consecutive symbol with the '!' symbol; display the new string s2"

Comment: the posted code fails to cleanly compile.  When compiling always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Comment: in general, do not use leading underscores '_' in variable and function names as that can create confusion because the compiler also prepends variable names and function names with a leading underscore and (for certain conditions) prepends names with 2 underscores.

Comment: The teacher should work on his formulations. In the phrase "the 3rd consecutive symbol" either the word _consecutive_ is superfluous or a word like _same_ is missing.

Answer (score 0):

"how can I replace it with the 3rd consecutive symbol" to replace the 3rd character in `s2`, you can use [array indexing](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm), i.e. replace the line `\\chrstr????` with this:

```
s2[2] = '!';
```

(and print it out of course, if that's what you want)

regarding how to confirm that s2 has 6 or more characters, just use an if statement:

```
if (length2 < 6) {
    /* do something to indicate string is too small */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To your question about how to confirm that S2 has 6 or more characters, it would be:

```
   if(strcmp(s2)>=6)
    {
        puts("\n\n-> S2 has 6 or more characters!!!");
    }
```

Now, if you want to recognize your 3rd character, it would be like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
    char s2[20];
    char third;

    printf("Hi! Enter a word so i can tell u its third character:  ");
    gets(s2);
    third  = s2[2];//it starts in 0, so your 3rd char is number "2"
    printf("\n-> The 3rd character is: %c", third);
}
```

Comment: this line: `if(strcmp(s2)>=6)` is wrong.   The `strcmp()` function compares two strings.  for this call, should use `strlen()`

Answer (score -1):

Possible algorithm to change the third consecutive character to '!' (if I understood it correctly):

```
1.   Set S2 iteration index (IDX) to 0
2.   While length of S2 > IDX + 2 do
2.1     If S2[IDX] == S2[IDX+1] == S2[IDX+2] then
2.1.1       S2[IDX+2] = '!'
2.1.2       IDX = IDX + 3 
2.2     Else
2.2.1       IDX = IDX + 1
```

Regarding verification that `s2` has 6 or more characters:

```
if (strlen(s2) < 6)
{
    // error message
}
```